adobe illustrator toolbar is the only one shown
like this
The homepage is not displaying correctly, similar to the screenshot linked here. This issue has been persistent despite multiple attempts to refresh the page, clear the cache, and delete cookies. Additionally, I have disabled illustrators extensions, and even restarted my device, yet the problem remains unresolved. This situation is significantly affecting my ability to access essential content and features on the application. I would greatly appreciate any detailed guidance or advanced troubleshooting steps that could help resolve this issue. Your assistance in rectifying this problem would be highly valued. Thank you in advance for your support

Try the menu: View > Show Artboards

